# Objects in Xcode Storyboard disappearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I was designing a storyboard in Xcode. Then I wrote a bit of code. When I came back, all my objects in a view had disappeared. Everything's working I just can't see them on my storyboard. But they appear when I run it. I really need to add a uiimageview to this view. But since there are no objects visible I can't. Any help appreciated[image: here's t running in the simulater] and [image: my storyboard in Xcode]

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be the case with you.

Suppose you add label in controller when size class is any other than `wAny hAny`. Suppose you are adding label in `wCompact hRegular` size class.An adding constraint for it.

[image]

[image]

Now you move to other size class. Suppose you change it to `wAny hAny`.
Now it looks will not find on storyboard and look like this.

[image]

[image]

In 4th image label looks like hidden and also not visible on storyboard.
So it is better to design storyboard in `wAny hAny` to make it visible in all size classes. Assuming this will be the case with you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add constraints to your views?If yes,you changed the size of top level view,just select views and CMD+Option+=(this is resizing view as suggested). If no,add constraints first. If you drag view with blue lines,this will sometimes work,not always.

Comment: Thanks, I made it in Compact Width,Any hight

Comment: @NiallKehoe oh,if you didn't make it in any,any,you must make constraints for different size class.To make repeat constraints in any,any is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Select a size class compact in width like "wCompact hAny"

See the width of size class in red box.

[image: See the width of size class in red box.]

[image: See the width of size class in red box]